# Get size of any download on youtube-dl?

Tags: video, 22.04, youtube, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I am running 22.04 LTS & would like to know how to get the size of any download on youtube-dl; How do I do that?

I have tried [GitHub issue Determining file size without downloading](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/4376) but on channels & playlists it gives a list of sizes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining file size without downloading](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/4376)

Comment: @cocomac No, I have to manually add the values, could you make an automatic script that adds them

Comment: Could you save the video URLs to a file and then use a simple loop (in Bash) to get all the values?

Comment: @cocomac I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Put all the URLs in a file, one on each line. Figure out the command to do it for just one URL, and then use a for loop to do it for all the URLs as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587725/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-line-in-a-file-with-bash)

Comment: @cocomac the playlist has 186 videos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137652/discussion-between-therandomguynamedjoe12-and-cocomac).

Comment: You could use something like `bc -l` to add the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an approximate size (this also works on playlists and channels):

```
youtube-dl 'http://www.snotr.com/video/13708/Drone_flying_through_fireworks' -j | jq .filesize_approx | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}'
```

For an exact size (this also works on playlists and channels):

```
youtube-dl http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-11-05/australia-to-staff-ebola-treatment-centre-in-sierra-leone/5868334 -j | jq .filesize | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}'
```

Partially taken from [Paul Dixon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450821/17011606)